# Stop ubuntu moving windows when screens power off

Tags: multiple-monitors

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with an AMD video card (driver=amdgpu) with 4 screens: 2x DisplayPort screens plus 2x HDMI (one via DP -> HDMI adapter).

**Whenever the screens power off, Ubuntu moves some of my windows off screen.** I have to recover them via alt+space, move, and then drag them back. There's a separate issue with move that makes them unrecoverable sometimes, at which point I have to close and re-open them.

**Is there some way to tell Ubuntu to just please leave my window positions alone?** I don't care if my windows go off the screen if I change screen configuration. I have lots of experience recovering off-screen windows...

Comment: I don't power off screens until after Ubuntu is fully suspended first. Then I power on screens before resuming Ubuntu. It works for me.